# How to configure Eclipse to automatically resolve and build multiple maven modules?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

**Here is my situation:**

- I'm trying to migrate from Ant to Maven
- My project has 3 artifacts: `shared api` (jar), `web app` (war), `desktop swing app` (jar). Latter 2 depends on shared api.
- At this moment  I'm trying to make web app part work. So I've created 4 poms: `eftracker` (root pom), `eftracker-parent`, `eftracker-shared`, `eftracker-web`.
- If I run `mvn package` on `eftracker` all works just perfect -- I have `eftracker-shared.jar` and `eftracker-web.war` created as expected
- I added `tomcat7-maven-plugin`to run web app with maven goal `tomcat7:run` to test changes made during development
- I also added `eftracker-shared` as a project to `eftracker-web` build path.

**My goal:**

- Now I want to work comfortably in Eclipse, meaning I want to change files, hit Run and in couple seconds be able to test my changes.
- During development I will change both: shared and web projects.

**My problem:**

- If I never run `mvn install` than an attempt to invoke `tomcat7:run` will lead to error: `Failed to execute goal on project eftracker-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.skarpushin:eftracker-web:war:1.503.0: Could not find artifact com.skarpushin:eftracker-shared:jar:1.503.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`
- It appears I have to `mvn clean install` shared project (or even on root module) each time I change it before I can execute `tomcat7:run` on web app and see recent changes.

**Question is:**

- Is it possible to make this process automatic?
- ...OR maybe there is other way how to minimize "maven overhead" during development?

**eftracker.pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.skarpushin</groupId>
    <artifactId>eftracker</artifactId>
    <version>1.503.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>eftracker</name>

    <modules>
        <module>eftracker-parent</module>
        <module>eftracker-shared</module>
        <module>eftracker-web</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**eftracker-parent/pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.skarpushin</groupId>
    <version>1.503.0</version>
    <artifactId>eftracker-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>eftracker-parent</name>

    <!-- ...some common properties, dependencies, build plugins... -->

</project>
```

**eftracker-web/pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.skarpushin</groupId>
        <artifactId>eftracker-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.503.0</version>
        <relativePath>../eftracker-parent</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>eftracker-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>ROOT##${project.version}</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.skarpushin</groupId>
            <artifactId>eftracker-shared</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ...other deps -->

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: I suggest you read about the [maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) and [maven POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) specifically the "Project Aggregation" section.

Comment: First remove that module `eftracker-parent` which should be in the `eftracker` (root module)..which then results in cleaning up the pom files (removing the `<relativePath>../...</relativePath>`....). Furthermore remove the configuration for maven-war-plugin just start with the conventions which are `src/main/webapp` location and the default name for the war file...(btw. using a more recent version.). Define all plugin versions in your parent module...You should build from the root module just by using `mvn clean package`...if this does not work something is wrong...

Comment: Eclipse automatically resolves maven dependencies in the workspace if the dependency projects are checked out in the workspace and the version of the dependency is a SNAPSHOT-version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears there are 2 things needs to be done:

- run `mvn compile` on parent project in that way all classes will appear in `../parent/target/classes` folder. Note that they'll be automatically updated by Eclipse if you change source code
- edit Eclipse run configuration and put this checkbox "Resolve Workspace artifacts"

Now I was able to run project as Maven build... with goal `tomcat7:run` and it worked without the need of parent project to be installed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use M2Eclipse
https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

> M2Eclipse provides tight integration for Apache Maven into the IDE
>   with the following features:
>
> - Launching Maven builds from within Eclipse
> - Dependency management for Eclipse build path based on Maven's pom.xml
> - Resolving Maven dependencies from the Eclipse workspace without installing to local Maven repository
> - Automatic downloading of the required dependencies from the remote Maven repositories
> - Wizards for creating new Maven projects, pom.xml and to enable Maven support on plain Java project
> - Quick search for dependencies in Maven remote repositories

Comment: I'm not sure about regular Eclipse distribution. But I use STS and it comes with m2e plugin pre-installed.